# Cannot register into my app because of a mail error

Tags: php, html, macos, sendmail

Im trying to make an app for iOS in swift3 but when i try to register i got an mail error (i made the register with an email activation link in order to complete the registration).

**register.php**

```
    // include email.php
require ("secure/email.php");

// store all class in $email var
$email = new email();

// store generated token in $token var
$token = $email->generateToken(20);

// save inf in 'emailTokens' table
$access->saveToken("emailTokens", $user["id"], $token);

// refer emailing information
$details = array();
$details["subject"] = "Email confirmation on Twitter";
$details["to"] = $user["email"];
$details["fromName"] = "Akhmed Idigov";
$details["fromEmail"] = "akhmedidigov@gmail.com";

// access template file
$template = $email->confirmationTemplate();

// replace {token} from confirmationTemplate.html by $token and store all content in $template var
$template = str_replace("{token}", $token, $template);

$details["body"] = $template;

$email->sendEmail($details);


  } else {
   $returnArray["status"] = "400";
   $returnArray["message"] = "Could not register with provided 
     infomraiton";
     }
```

**email.php**

```
class email {


// Generate unique token for user when he got confirmation email message
function generateToken($length) {

    // some characters
    $characters = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM1234567890";

    // get length of characters string
    $charactersLength= strlen($characters);

    $token = '';

    // generate random char from $characters every time until it is less than $charactersLength
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $token .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength-1)];
    }

    return $token;

}


// Open confirmation template user gonna receive
function confirmationTemplate() {

    // open file
    $file = fopen("templates/confirmationTemplate.html", "r") or die("Unable to open file");

    // store content of file in $template var
    $template = fread($file, filesize("templates/confirmationTemplate.html"));

    fclose($file);

    return $template;

}


// Open confirmation template user gonna receive
function resetPasswordTemplate() {

    // open file
    $file = fopen("templates/resetPasswordTemplate.html", "r") or die("Unable to open file");

    // store content of file in $template var
    $template = fread($file, filesize("templates/resetPasswordTemplate.html"));

    fclose($file);

    return $template;

}


// Send email with php
function sendEmail($details) {

    // information of email
    $subject = $details["subject"];
    $to = $details["to"];
    $fromName = $details["fromName"];
    $fromEmail = $details["fromEmail"];
    $body = $details["body"];

    // header required by some of smtp or mail sites
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;content=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: " . $fromName . " <" . $fromEmail . ">" . "\r\n"; // From Akhmed Idigov <akhmed@gmail.com>

    // php func to send email finaly
    mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);

}


}



?>
```

[image: this is what I get when I register]

This is what I get when I register

I can provide any other informations if needed.

Comment: This appears to be nothing to do with Swift, iOS or Objective-C. It is a problem with sendmail on your macOS server running your php.

Comment: and what should i do or where i can find some help? i need to fix this as soon as possible. thanks

Comment: Install a server that supports mailing? Buy a hosting that supports mailing?

Comment: i followed a tutorial and what i have done is to edit the /etc/postfix/main.cf file to add some lines (relayhost=smtp.gmail.com:587 / smtp_sasl_auth_enable=yes and others )...

What its strange is that i enter for eg. **date | mail -s testing xx@gmail.com** i got this email. What is wrong?

Comment: nobody can help me? :(